# "Unsupported indexer" when trying to access a TypeScript dictionary

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to make a [Minecraft MakeCode](https://minecraft.makecode.com) extension in TypeScript and a dictionary is needed to map a string to a corresponding string:

```
const chars:{[index:string]:string} = {
  "A": "MSOJOQJ",
  "B": "JWIQWIQ"
  // ...
};
```

However when I try to look up a value of the dictionary:

```
let look = chars["A"];
```

TypeScript throws an error that it is `unsupported indexer`.

Setting the key-value pairs for the dictionary doesn't work either:

```
chars["C"] = "HIHWQHQ"; // unsupported indexer
```

Is there any fault in my code or is TypeScript bugged/too strict?

Comment: Your code works fine for me in TypeScript 3.2. Looking here: https://makecode.com/language, it appears that MakeCode has their own special version of TypeScript that doesn’t support all the standard features of normal TypeScript.

Answer (score 0):

After further looking into the MakeCode environment, it appears that while it doesn't support dictionary indexers on mapped types, it does support dot access:

```
const dicto: { [key: string]: string } = {
    hello: "world",
    goodbye: "friends",
};

dicto["hello"] = "wow!"; // error
const b = dicto["goodbye"]; // error

dicto.hello = "wow!"; // ok
const c = dicto.goodbye; // ok, c inferred to be of type string
```